# postgres - remote connection - PgAdmin connects, php/python doesn't

Tags: php, python, postgresql, psycopg2, pgadmin

I've got a VPN to my server network set up. Everything works fine, I can ping servers and ssh around the network. Except for the database connection.

When I use PgAdmin on ubuntu and insert connection details (ip,host etc.) it connects without problems. But when I try the same with Python psycopg2/PyGreSql I either get a can't resolve hostname error (name or service not known) or no hba.conf rule error. I added the rule and it didn't change anything.

I reckon that if the rule didn't work PgAdmin wouldn't connect.

PgSql ver: 8.3.7 on Debian 4.3.2
Pgadmin3 ver - newest for ubuntu (1.18.1)
psycopg2/PyGreSql - newest versions from pip.

While I'm not sure about psycopg2, PyGreSql should support my old database version, so that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: I reckon you should show the exact error message text :p . Separately, 8.3.7, *really*? Any reason you're relying on a fossil database?

Comment: Yep there is a reason. The whole server room and the software is fossil and I have no means of updating it. This place is hell I tell you.

Problem fixed by restarting the DB - I guess the hbconf rule didn't apply for some reason. Wonder why PgAdmin was still able to connect from the same PC?

Comment: Per the documenation, `pg_hba.conf` changes only take effect when you reload the server - either restarting it, using `SELECT pg_reload_conf()`, or sending a `SIGHUP` to the postmaster (possibly via `pg_ctl reload`). I expect your PgAdmin connection worked because you were connection with different options - different database name, username, source host address, ssl mode, etc.